# Run haproxy.disable_server when haproxy runs as multiple processes

Tags: centos, haproxy, saltstack

We have few application server and 2 load-balanders (HAProxy). Cloud in implemented with SaltStack. When there is need to disable certain app server, we log into salt master and run:

`for i in {1..20}; do salt '*.lb-app' haproxy.disable_server 1.app app; done`

Since haproxy is running with `nbproc 4`, only one call doesn't switch the traffic. So by calling is 20 time there is a decent probability that all 4 processes will disable given server.

I was wondering if there is more elegant solution.